# In silverstripe Can we create Vanity URL for the member profile?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

In silverstripe Can we create Vanity URL for the member profile like "mydomain.com/john-doe"?

I tried to do it via the routes.yml but it is breaking the other URLs like admin and other frontend pages(about us).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though there's no simple yaml configuration for doing so.
The easiest way to do this is probably with the [silverstripe/redirectedurls](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-redirectedurls) module which gives you a section in the CMS for setting arbitrary URL redirections.

If that doesn't quite do what you're after, you could set up `VirtualPage`s for each such page - though that will clutter your sitetree somewhat (which you could alleviate by hiding those from the sitetree and setting up a custom `ModelAdmin` for managing them).